# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 - apt-get and most packages broken - Unable to correct dependencies

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I fired off an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, which went south as far as dependencies are concerned. Unfortunately, I was inside of a virtualenv, which may explain why some of the upgrades didn't succeed.

Firing off `sudo apt-get update` gets me

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libxapian-dev'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-dev'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-wayland'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-x11'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5sysguard-dev'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-seclib
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-sabre-http
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libxapian-dev'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-dev'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-wayland'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-x11'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5sysguard-dev'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package xserver-xorg
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package xserver-xorg
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

running `apt-get -v
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Dec  8 2016 16:23:38`

Trying a `sudo apt-get -f install` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
empathy : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
        Recommends: nautilus-sendto-empathy but it is not installable
gir1.2-cogl-1.0 : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
gnome-bluetooth : Depends: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 (= 3.8.2.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 3.18.2-1ubuntu2 is installed
                Depends: obexd-client but it is not installable
                Recommends: unity-control-center but it is not installed or
                            gnome-control-center but it is not installed
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
gstreamer1.0-clutter : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
hplip : Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
        Depends: libsane-hpaio (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
        Depends: hplip-data (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
        Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not installed
irssi : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
kdelibs-bin : Depends: libkdecore5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
            Depends: libkdeui5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
            Depends: libkjsapi4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
            Depends: libkjsembed4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
kdelibs5-plugins : Depends: libkrosscore4 (= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5) but 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2 is installed
                    Depends: kdelibs-bin (= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5) but 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2 is installed
libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libapparmor-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
libapt-pkg-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libauthen-pam-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libbit-vector-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libcairo-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
libclone-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libclutter-gst-2.0-0 : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
libcogl-pango15 : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
libcompress-raw-lzma-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libcrypt-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libdate-calc-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libdatetime-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libdbd-mysql-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.5) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
libfcgi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libfile-fcntllock-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libgail-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libgnome2-canvas-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libgnome2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libgnome2-vfs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) but it is not installed
libgtk2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libio-pty-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libjson-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libk3b6 : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
libkcal4 : Depends: libical1 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
libkcalcore4 : Depends: libical1 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
libkcmutils4 : Depends: libkdecore5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
                Depends: libkdeui5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
libkdeclarative5 : Depends: libkdecore5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
                    Depends: libkdeui5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
libkio5 : Depends: libstreamanalyzer0 (>= 0.7.8) but it is not installable
libkolab0 : Depends: libkolabxml1 but it is not installable
libkrosscore4 : Depends: libkdecore5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
                Depends: libkdeui5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2) but 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5 is installed
liblist-moreutils-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libmyth-0.27-0 : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.6) but it is not installable
libnet-dbus-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libnet-dns-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
libossp-uuid-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libpackage-stash-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libpango-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libparams-classify-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libparams-util-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libparams-validate-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libperl5.18 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.3) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3 is installed
libperlio-gzip-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libplasma3 : Depends: libkcmutils4 (= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.5) but 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2 is installed
libpurple0 : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
            Recommends: libpurple-bin but it is not installed
libqt5gui5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
            Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
libqt5widgets5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
libsnmp-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
libsocket6-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) but it is not installed
libsub-identify-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libsub-name-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libterm-readkey-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libtext-soundex-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libtotem0 : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
libuuid-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
libvlc5 : Depends: libvlccore7 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not installable
libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
perl-tk : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
perlmagick : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
python3-apt : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-brlapi : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-crypto : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-gdbm : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
                    Depends: python3-gi (= 3.12.0-1ubuntu1) but 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
python3-libapparmor : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-lxml : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-pkg-resources : Depends: python3:any (< 3.5)
python3-pycurl : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-pykde4 : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-pyqt4 : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-setuptools : Depends: python3:any (< 3.5)
python3-sip : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
rhythmbox-mozilla : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist : Depends: rhythmbox (>= 3.0) but it is not installed
                            Depends: rhythmbox (< 3.1) but it is not installed
rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
                    Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
rhythmbox-ubuntuone : Depends: rhythmbox (>= 2.95.5) but it is not installed
totem : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
uuid-dev : Depends: libuuid1 (= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) but 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.9 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

My sources:

```
egrep -v '^#|^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main universe multiverse restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
egrep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory
```

It looks like I am running 16.04.04 as far as I can tell:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Any ideas how to fix this?